# python File read buffer boundary

Tags: python, file-io

when we use function open() to open a file,we may set the buffersize for performance . But I just doubt if we set 1024,but the data in file is like this:

1999999999 3232344 54354364576 2343243254 6453623453245r3245235 5342453245233333333333333333 534545454364536 4355545...

So I don't know whether this will cut off one number，just as first read,buffer will be 1999999999 3232344 54354364576 2343243254 6453623453245r3245235 53424532,

And next we read buffer will be 45233333333333333333 534545454364536 4355545,and so on.

Or python's buffer implement had solve this question ? Can anyone give me some pointers ? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What's your problem exactly ? You write "I doubt", but what do you doubt of ? You write "just as first read" (by the way, I think you wanted to write 'at first read') : but that can be ``f.read()`` and all the file will be read, or ``for line in f`` and the lines will be fetched one after the other in the buffer and the buffer repeatedly filled as many times it is necessary , or ``f.read(450)`` and only 450 characters will be read.....

Comment: You also write "next we read buffer": we don't read in buffer, that's the computer that manages the filling of buffer and reading in buffer. And what kind of problem has the "buffer implement"ation to solve according to you ?

Comment: ok,sorry for my poor English .I just can't understand computer how to manage buffer?An extreme example is:we set buffer size 9,and we read(4) every time,so buffer will auto do the next IO and we do not read 1 when the third read？

Comment: Let's say you have a file of 3 GB and you do ``for line in f``. The computer doesn't load the 3 GB in the RAM in only one chunk, and it no more reads the bytes in the files until each end of line and stops there before reading the other line later. It reads a chunk of bytes at once, let's say 8192 bytes, in which are lying 25 lines and it puts these bytes in the buffer. Let's say now that the algorithm of a code needs the reading of 40 lines.

Comment: Then the 25 first lines will be read in the buffer, and after that, another chunk of 8192 will be read and placed in the buffer, and then the next 15 lines will be read in the renewed content of the buffer. The part corresponding to the last 10 lines in the buffer won't be read but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Let the computer managing when it fetches bytes in the hard drive to put them in the buffer to fulfill the needs of the algorithm. I don't think the understanding of the precise mechanisms implied are of great interest. Better is to wonder what size to affect to a buffer. Now, I'm not a specialist of the buffers' questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the read method without any arguments it will return the entire file content. You can use the size parameter if you only want to read a part of the file at a time.

See the documentation for more info http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Thanks. But I think your answer may be about read method's argument,but I means open method arguments.

Comment: Ok. Can you clarify what your question is?